# Define xml animation into Java

Tags: android, animation, translate-animation

Is it possible to write slide_out_left animation using java?

Here is my animation xml.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:duration="300" android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%" />
</set>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible:

```
view.animate().translationX(_amount_).setDuration(_time in ms_).start();
```

So, you will have to calculate translation distance by yourself. 
Note: if you translate to 0 later, after some other translations - it will move to starting position.

To complete slide in effect try to use withStartAction also.